# sails js wont load file after refresh

Tags: javascript, sails.js

When I try to refresh my app with the **cache disabled**, then most times sailsjs will serve all the files except for 1 or 2. These files, which seem to be random, will stall out but finally be served after 2 minutes. The chosen files could be any of the javascript files in my project: jquery, angular controllers, jquery dependencies. But it works just fine when the cache is on.

Comment: does adding `app.disable('etag')` work?

Comment: wait, no it didnt work :/

Comment: Would be nice if you could share your response headers for reference.